# Add image on foreground of UITableView and scroll Enable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, scroll

I have a `UITableView` and I want to put a `UIImageView` with transparency in the foreground above the `UITableView`.

The problem is if I add the `UIImageView` above the `UITableView` I can't scroll on the `UITableView` since it's under the `UIImageView`.

Is there a way to have a `UIImageView` above a `UITableView` and still have the ability to scroll on the `UITableView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add image programmatically like this.

```
[self.demoTableView insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultThumbNail.png"]] atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I follow your question. Simply use the following to disable touches on your imageView to allow the scrollView (tableView) underneath it to accept touches.

```
_imageView.userIneractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: I believe it was the previous answer I gave which showed how to have the background image scroll with the tableview scrolling. (misunderstanding). Although a comment with the -1 would have been nice! A clearer question would help since it appears other answers aren't following it too clearly as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want, you have to 'pass' touches through your image view. One way to do this is to subclass the `UIImageView` and implement `- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{}` method of `UIView`. If you return `NO` or `FALSE` from that method, your custom `UIImageView` will pass through all the touches to the subview beneath it. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here the code for **UITable**

If you want put a Background image under the tableview you can use this code inside a **viewDidLoad** or **viewWillDidAppear**

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
```

or

```
// here you can setting RGB color and Alpha channel
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/256.0) green:(255/256.0) blue:(255/256.0) alpha:1.0];
```

If you want change the View of a single table or tableView design using this under the **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
UIImage *background = [self cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *cellBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
    cellBackgroundView.image = background;
    cell.backgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
```

And create a UIImage Cell Background:

```
- (UIImage *)cellBackgroundForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger rowCount = [self tableView:[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;
    UIImage *background = nil;

    if (rowIndex == 0) {
        background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TopOfCell.png"];
    } else if (rowIndex == rowCount - 1) {
        background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MiddleCell.png"];
    } else {
        background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BottomCell.png"];
    }

    return background;
}
```

In this case if you put the same IMG in all 3 levels you can see a unique BG for the cell and you don't need coloring your TableView with a UIImage in foreground, you can design directly on the cell, example:

**TopOfCell.png**  is a first cell and you can put a IMG Height 10px width 300px with corner radius 5, in the middle you can use a img width 300px height 1136px with some graphics, and in the bottom mirrored the first one, you can see your table with graphics pragmatically.

I Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Just add the UIImageView into the UITableView as a subview in the controller's viewDidLoad: method.
Code tells everything:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name"];
    [self.tableview addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Pay attention to the imageview's frame as it could be inserted into a container controller, in that case you have to adjust the size.

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing it in xib then it can be done by following steps ...

1. Drag n drop UIImageView to your UIView
2. set the image u want to set to it.
3. Drag n drop  UITableView on it adjust its frame according to our need.
4. select the tableview outlet and set its background color to clear color

thats all ...